# How to include template within a directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

How can one include a .html template within an angular directive's template?

The current way I am including a template successfully pulls that template's HTML into the directive template, but the variables within the template are not linking to the controller.

This is what I'm currently doing:

**_directive_template.html**

```
<section>
  ...
 <div ng-include="'/templates/_template_to_be_included.html'"></div>
  ...
</section>
```

**_template_to_be_included.html**

```
 <form>
    <input ng-model="some_value">
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
 </form>
```

**Directive**

```
...
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.some_value  // not correctly linking to some_value within included template 
      }
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: link,
    templateUrl: '/templates/_directive_template.html'
  };
....
```

When I copy and paste the HTML of _template_to_be_included.html directly into the Directive Template (instead of using ng-include as above), everything works and `some_value` is correctly linked between the its place in the form and its place in the controller.

How do I properly include a template into a directive template and have its variables linked to their counterparts in the directive? It seems ng-include should have worked, since it will "fetch and compile" the specified template...

[Plunkr:](http://plnkr.co/edit/D0HjA4lbTtL0zrnWqQGA?p=preview) 
Type some input and hit "update"

Comment: it should work.. can you create a plunker

Comment: using the templateURL property in the directive definition is the standard way

Comment: Are you saying you are embedding the ng-include in the template markup?  Something like:   template: <section><div ng-include="" /></section>  ?   If so I wonder if you are running into timing issues - i.e. it compiles down the directive before the ng-include has completed.   Like @entre said, would be nice to see a plunker.

Comment: @user1821052 I am already using templateUrl to tie a template (`_directive_template.html`) to my directive. The problem is that `_directive_template.html` needs to include another template. @ your second comment: Yep, that is what I mean. Updated my Q to clarify. I'll work on a plunkr.

Comment: What happens if you use template instead of templateUrl?   So embed the markup along with the ng-include.   Since both templateUrl and ng-include do $http requests perhaps the templateUrl completes (and compiles) before the ng-include?

Comment: I would like to modularize my templates though, and not have to write them inline in the directive. How can I do that with just `template:`?
This gets to the heart of my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/D0HjA4lbTtL0zrnWqQGA?p=preview
type something into input and hit "update"

Comment: Also,  The docs suggest against using `template:` for large templates, and also my template needs to use single quotes `'` for ng-include, which break out of the `template:` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I understood the question. I put together a Plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/L4ZN5XhOpex6U5MRKsZ4?p=preview

```
<div>
  <h1>Directive Template</h1>
  <p>This is just some garbage text.</p>

  <h1>ng-include template</h1>
  <div ng-include="'_template_to_be_included.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This actually gets to the heart of my problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/D0HjA4lbTtL0zrnWqQGA?p=preview
Some_value is returning undefined when used in a function upon submit

Comment: Give me a little bit and I will update the plunker to help you with your issue.

Comment: Late response, but in case you still need it: you loose the scope on ng-init. Change your alert(scope.some_value) with alert(this.some_value) and you're all set